# Крашит бота vk-api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Со временем крашит бота на VK-API

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/botalaz3.py", line 1283, in <module>
photo = upload.photo_messages('kartina2.jpg')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vk_api/upload.py", line 102, in photo_messages
return self.vk.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(**response.json())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Пробывал делать EXCEPT, но видимо не так сделал. Помогите пожалуйста

Вот метод отправки фото

```
def send_photo(user_id,message,attachment,keyboard=None):
    post = {
    "user_id": user_id,
    "attachment": attachment,
    "message": message,
    "random_id": 0
}
if keyboard != None:
    post["keyboard"] = keyboard.get_keyboard()

session.method("messages.send", post)
```

И сообщений
def send_message(user_id, message, keyboard=None):
post = {
"user_id": user_id,
"message": message,
"random_id": 0
}

```
if keyboard != None:
    post["keyboard"] = keyboard.get_keyboard()

session.method("messages.send", post)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

attachment надо загружать через vk.upload или другие методы. вы делаете это вне функции?

upd: перечитав ваш вопрос, насколько я понял, код у вас запускается, но крашится.

очень странно, что вам не помогло try
оберните вашу функцию, в которой может возникнуть ошибка в try:

```
try:
    send_photo(*args*)
except:
    pass
```